# Windows Service in C# with "ServiceBase.CanStop" property as true

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I'm trying to create a service that can not be easily stopped by the user. I do not know if I'm on the right track, I think not. But I found the property "CanStop" in ServiceBase class and decided to test it. When True, the service, the fact, can not be stopped unless it is killed by the Process Manager.

My question: Is there some .NET elegant way to cancel or ignore this option? Because my idea is that the service can be stopped by a Service Manager Console but nerver by the services.msc.

If I'm in the wrong way: How can I have a service that prevents the user to stop the service? Only through group policies?

Comment: `Because my idea is that the service can be stopped by a Service Manager Console but nerver by the services.msc`  Why?  That just prefers one service control UI over another.

Comment: In fact, this service should never be stopped. It even has a Guardian Software to recover any undesirable and possible accidental fall not protected, for example. However, it is possible to setup this service a few settings that can be applied only when it is stoped. These settings are made by the Manager, who now holds the guardian software on stand-by.

Comment: What does this have to do with WCF?  WCF and Windows Services are **NOT** the same thing (though a Windows Service *can* be used to host a WCF service).